# How to save the output of a linux command in dictionary?

Tags: python

I am trying to get list of all files and there modification time in a key to value pair.

I've tried to store the output by using subprocess.check_output("ls -lh | grep -v '^d' | awk '{print $9,$8}'", shell=True ) but as it is returning me bytes I am not able to convert that in to dictionary.

```py
text = subprocess.check_output("ls -lh | grep -v '^d' | awk '{print $9,$8}'", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call [`.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) on the output so you will work with a string. Then you will have to do some [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) magic to construct the dictionary:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output("ls -lh | grep -v '^d' | awk '{print $9,$8}'", shell=True).decode()

d = {}
for line in output.split('\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        file_name, mod_time = line.split()
        d[file_name] = mod_time 

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.decode()` method to convert from bytes to string. Such as:

```
text = subprocess.check_output("ls -lh | grep -v '^d' | awk '{print $9,$8}'", shell=True).decode('utf-8')
```

I assume you'll handle the rest from here?